# Setting a static IP address on Debian 10, any reason to set dns-nameservers, broadcast or network?

Tags: debian, network-interface, ip

I'm setting a static IP address on Debian 10.

```
$ vim /etc/network/interfaces

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask x.x.x.x
    gateway x.x.x.x
#   broadcast x.x.x.x
#   network x.x.x.x
#   dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
```

Is there any reason to set `dns-nameservers` in this file if I already have a bunch of nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

`broadcast` and `network` seem to be auto-recognized by the OS. Is there any reason to include them in this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the nameservers, probably not as long as it does not get overwritten.

For `broadcast` & `network`, possibly. If they are not set, the system will fall back to typical network classifcation. That is they will be defined as to whether the IP address is a class `A` (/8), `B` (/16) or `C` (/24).

Typically you will use `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.12.X.X/16` or `192.168.X.X/24`, which for `192.168.X.X/24`, would be setup as `network: 192.168.X.0` and `broadcast: 192.168.X.255`. But it's possible if you have subneted these or if you have been assigned a subnet, in which case, yes, you should define them. There are other address subnets you could use.

Comment: The output of `ip address show` and `ifconfig` show I'm on a `/23`. My host gave me my netmask of `255.255.254.0`, which I believe confirms the /23. Based on that, I can now determine my network address. So I will take your advice and enter the broadcast and network. Thanks for taking the time.